# Expression language for PutEmail Message Property?

Tags: apache-nifi

I am new to niFi. I have to send an email whose body is a string. I have configured the PutEmail and it is being sent. The body of the email however is not. For the Message property I have set the value as ${mqtt.message} and ${payload}. I wish to send the string message which is in the payload of message sent by publisher.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flow files have content and attributes. Expression language can only reference attributes. So using ${mqtt.message} or ${payload} means your flow must have attributes name mqtt.message or payload.

You can see the attributes by using provenance, or by stopping a processor and using the "list queue" functionality.

If the data you want to send as the message is in the content of your flow file, then you can use ExtractText to extract the entire content into an attribute.